# How to build a 3rd party package in ember v2.6?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js, vega, vega-lite

Trying to integrate vega-lite npm package into a single component for ember 2.6 .Brocolli is giving following error:

> The Broccoli Plugin: [object Object] failed with:
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'vega-lite' from
>
> '/home/zemoso012/gg/ember-trello/tmp/stub_generator-output_path-A3jgYyCP.tmp'

Answer (score 0):

I created an [Ember addon to import vega@3.0](https://github.com/GCheung55/ember-vega). At the time of this answer, `vega` is in 3.0.0-beta.20.

If you need to load `vega-lite`, take a look at `ember-vega`'s `index.js` to see how it's done.